# Is anyone here familiar with differential field theory or differential galois theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, differential

I came across [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) today for differential algebra which looks interesting, but I do not see a concrete example to start with. Would anyone be able to provide an example on using Liouville's theorem to show the integral of simple elementary functions like $x^2$ or $\log(x)$ are elementary?

Or otherwise are there completely different methods of addressing this problem maybe related to Lie groups?